# including OWIN in a desktop app

Tags: c#, owin

I've written an OWIN app that runs fine as a console app but I'd like to include it as part of a desktop app I'm writing. Every example I can find for starting an OWIN app starts it up as a console ap and runs it till a key is pressed, how do I move this into the desktop app?

I was thinking of just putting the start up code into a thread and just setting it off on an infinite loop, is that the best way or is there an alternative?

At the moment I've got this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:9000"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press [enter] to quit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Which starts the OWIN server running as a console app but I want to be able to include it in a desktop app and start and stop it with a button press. How do I rewrite this to work like that?

Comment: I would suggest that you implement your thread idea, then take it over to [codereview.se] for help.  As written, this question is too vague.

Comment: What more information do you need to remove the vagueness?

Comment: Show the code you've tried and how its failed would do it.

Comment: I've not written anything and so nothing has failed, I'm asking the best way to do it before I write any code. At the moment I've got the start up as shown in here http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana . I want to move that so rather than being a console app I can put the code into a desktop app and start and stop it with a button.

Comment: The problem with "best way" is that is so broad and subjective.  Two things that are off topic for stackoverflow.  Get something more concrete and post it on [codereview.se] as i suggested in my first comment.  Takes more work, but you'll be able to narrow down a solid bit of code that way.

Comment: You could post it here too of course... there is a bit of cross over between the sites, but [codereview.se] is for just that.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question, we'll see if others agree with me.

Comment: Though what you are looking for is pretty easily accomplished.  Get a new winform app, put two buttons on the form and double click on them to generate the click event code.  Then put your start code in the start button event and the stop code in the stop button event.

Answer (score 2):

When you call WebApp.Start("some_addreess") it automatically starts in a background thread, you need not manage it in your thread. Just mantain the reference to disposable which needs to be closed before quit or on stop.

A sample code could be like below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IDisposable server;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeOwin();
        }

        private void InitializeOwin()
        {
            server = WebApp.Start<OwinStartup>("http://localhost:8989/");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To be called before quit or stop button
        /// </summary>
        private void CallMeBeforeClose()
        {
            server.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class OwinStartup
    {
        //initialize owin startup class and do other stuff
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            appBuilder.UseWelcomePage("/");
        }
    }
```